# aws cdk to use non-default profile

Tags: aws-cdk

I don't want to use my default aws profile  and account for cdk development

So I created a new account  and a new  profile `cdkprof` using `aws configure --profile cdkprof` .

I have verified in `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files that the new profile created correctly. running `export AWS_PROFILE=cdkprof && aws configure list && aws sts get-caller-identity` returns me my profile details correctly.

I have also exported

- CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
- CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
- AWS_PROFILE,
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and
- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

and these are available as environment variables in bash.

However when I try to run :

```
$ npx cdk bootstrap --profile cdkprof
```

I get the error

```
Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK or through the environment
```

How do  I use my new profile and account with the cdk commands?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the aws cli only looks for the /.aws/credentials. You might need to put this into the path where you are running npx. Have not used npx but I do a lot of aws with php and command line.

Comment: was worth a try. but no luck, adding ~/.aws to path did not work, nor did installing aws-cdk globally and not calling via npx.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, CDK commands will use the default AWS CLI profile. However, you can specify a named profile for a project by adding it to the file which handles CDK commands. For a TypeScript project, this is done in `cdk.json` at the project root:

```
{
  "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/project.ts",
  "profile": "cdkprof",
  "context": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, your named profile will be used when you run commands such as `cdk bootstrap`.

Comment: still don't know why cli isn't picking up my profile, I would prefer not to hardcode profile as I want to share this code. But for now, this approach works enough to get me started. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work

`~/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

[london]
aws_access_key_id = bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aws_secret_access_key = bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb


[paris]
aws_access_key_id = cccccccccccccccccccc
aws_secret_access_key = cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

`~/.aws/config`

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1

[profile london]
region = eu-west-2

[profile paris]
region = eu-west-3
```

then

`cdk bootstrap --profile london` etc work as youd hope

Answer (score -1):

the profile name in credentials and config file should be the same,
for example:

```
-credentials
[cdk]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxx
-config
[cdk]
region = "us-east-1"
```

Comment: the name in the config file must be prefixed with "profile": `[profile cdk]`

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me: `cdk bootstrap aws://[ACCOUNT-NUMBER]/[REGION] --profile [YOUR PROFILE]`

Comment: What version cdk are you using?